# Prove that $\dim L(F)+\dim\ker(L)=\dim(F+\ker(L))$ for every subspace $F$ and every linear transformation $L$ of finite dimensional vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that $\dim L(F) + \dim \ker(L)=\dim(F+\ker(L))$ for every subspace $F$ and every linear transformation $L$ of finite dimensional vector space $V$.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Have you already learned the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)? Because it is an immediate consequence of it.

Comment: I know rank-nullity theorem but i dont know how to use it to solve this problem.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Apply rank-nullity to the linear map induced by $L$ from $F + \ker(L)$ to $L(F)$.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.It`s really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Consider the short exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow \ker L\longrightarrow F+\ker L\longrightarrow (F+\ker L)/\ker L\longrightarrow 0 $$
and use the *second isomorphism theorem*: $\;(F+\ker L)/\ker L\simeq F/(F\cap\ker L)$, and observe that $\;F/(F\cap \ker L)\simeq L(F)$ by the *first isomorphism theorem*.